# Unable to fetch avail zones data using data source in a specific aws account

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm getting an error "known after apply" when i try to query availability zones via data source for any region ina specific account.But the same is working fine for other aws accounts.Also this was working fine previously and now it is not working

My data.tf file content

```
data "aws_availability_zones" "available_subnet" {
  state = "available"
}
```

my provider.tf

```
provider "aws" {
    profile = "profile-dev"
    region = "eu-central-1"
}
```

If i try below via terraform console then getting error

```
> data.aws_availability_zones.available_subnet.names
(known after apply)
>
```

But if try the same with different account and it is working as expected as below

```
> data.aws_availability_zones.available_subnet.names
tolist([
  "us-west-2a",
  "us-west-2b",
  "us-west-2c",
  "us-west-2d",
])
```

Is there any issue within the account privilege or settings(it was working fine previously).Able to query the same through aws cli

```
# aws ec2 describe-availability-zones --region=eu-central-1 --profile=profile-dev|grep -i zoneName
            "ZoneName": "eu-central-1a",
            "ZoneName": "eu-central-1b",
            "ZoneName": "eu-central-1c",
```

Is it terraform issue?

Comment: `(known after apply)` is not an error, it means that a simple `terraform plan` will not fetch the data from the API, you'll need to `terraform apply` in order to get those values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found its not an issue of terraform or aws.It seems after run terraform apply and run it from console,it brings the output.Thats what happened on my another aws account where i'm able to fetch the zones.So terraform console only brings data source outputs only if it is in state file.